# How to get object Prefix from string type of object name?

Tags: apex, describesobjectresult

I have following code to return prefix of any object based on API name of object passed as string. :

```
private static String  getObjectPrefixID(String objName){

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = genericObject.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
        return keyPrefix;
    }
```

I am getting error as:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String

Not sure how to get the prefix ID in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> m  = Schema.getGlobalDescribe() ;
system.debug('==>m is==>'+m);
Schema.SObjectType s = m.get('Account') ;
system.debug('==>Sobject Type is ==>'+s);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe() ;
String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
return keyPrefix;
```

Replace Account with your Object API name.

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/158070/50252) (and the other existing alternative) relies on the use of `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`. While this is quick, easy and obvious to code, it comes at a performance cost.

The first access to this from your org in a while (the describes get cached by Salesforce for a time it seems, or at least some of the underlying metadata does) this can cost over 700ms to return the map - timing testing on a scratch org using `Datetime.now().getTime()` before and after - only dropping to between 100 and 300ms thereafter on the same org. If you consider you have a maximum of 10 seconds CPU time for a given transaction against the server, this is a real waste. (It must be said, the `Limits.getCpuTime` method doesn't count the entire cost here, but it is still over 100ms from my testing.)

On the other hand, the following method takes between 2 and 15ms (and averaging around 5ms) to execute, giving the same result:

```
String typeName = ...; // E.g. 'Case' or 'Account' etc.
SObject instance = (SObject) Type.forName('Schema.' + typeName).newInstance();
String idPrefix = instance.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
```

Getting the `Type` for a given *typeName* is fast and efficient. The modest overhead of creating an empty `SObject` from the `Type` has little impact on heap or CPU, and getting the describe for the instance is very fast.

Clearly, if your code needs many different ID prefixes **in one transaction** (e.g. more than 10-15 different objects' prefixes) it can become more efficient to use the global describes.

**UPDATE**:

If you go to the trouble of using the updated `Schema.describeSObjects`, ensuring that the `SObjectDescribeOptions.DEFERRED` option is applied, you can get even better performance. For example:

```
String typeName = ...;
List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> describes = Schema.describeSObjects(new String[] { typeName }, SObjectDescribeOptions.DEFERRED);
String idPrefix = describes[0].getKeyPrefix();
```

This, surprisingly, has better performance compared with the use of `Type.forName`. With my testing (on the same scratch org) I got real time timing of between 2 and 8 milliseconds (the latter actually not on first use of the org for a while, which was 5ms), and a CPU limit timing of between 1 and 3 milliseconds. This makes it the fastest and most repeatable way to access the schema to get the ID key prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the object name and you will get the prefix of the object

```
public static String getObjectKeyPrefix(String objName){
    /*objName ='Account';*/
    schema.sObjectType sObjType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName);
    return (sObjType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
}
```