# How to dynamically query any Field's Picklist values using Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components

In the line - objApi.fieldApi.getDescribe().getPicklistValues(), I am trying to pass ObjApi as Object API and fieldApi as Field API in the parameters. So that it will form like this -
**Account.Industry__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()**. However, I am getting an error on this line:=
***Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDescribe() from the type String***

Please help

```
 /*TO RETREIVE FIELD PICKLIST FROM OBJECT BY PASSING OBJECT API AND FIELD API
 @param1: STRING - OBJECT API
 @Param2: STRING - FIELD API  
 */
 @AuraEnabled
 public static List<String> getPickList(String objApi, String fieldApi){

    List<string> picklistvalues = new List<string>();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : objApi.fieldApi.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()){
        picklistvalues.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
    }
     return picklistvalues;
 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to convert the String (*SObjec tName*) from `String` to `SObjectType` with `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName)`. Then use `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`,`Schema.SObjectField` and `Schema.PicklistEntry` as below to get the Picklist values.

```
String objectName = 'Contact';
String fieldName ='LeadSource';
  
Schema.SObjectType objSobjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName) ;
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribeSobject = objSobjectType.getDescribe() ;
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fields = objDescribeSobject.fields.getMap() ;
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
    System.debug(pickListVal.getLabel() +' '+pickListVal.getValue());
}
```

> Update 1

As Phil W mentioned `Schema.getGlobalDescribe` is not efficient rather use the following method. You can get the details [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158067/how-to-get-object-prefix-from-string-type-of-object-name/380019#380019).

```
String typeName = ...; // E.g. 'Case' or 'Account' etc.
SObject instance = (SObject) Type.forName('Schema.' + typeName).newInstance();
```

> Update 2

As Elijah mentioned the above method doesn't support Record Type. Looks like it is not currently possible with native Apex, but there is an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVwoUAF/getting-picklist-values-based-on-record-type) you can upvote. As suggested use Tooling API instead.

Comment: Do not use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe`. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158067/how-to-get-object-prefix-from-string-type-of-object-name/380019#380019) for why and how to do the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: This doenst take record type in picture. Rather use Tooling api to get this information

Comment: The Apex PM's suggestion was to use the [UI Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm) to cater for recordtypes